# Merging 1D arrays into a 2D array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Is there a built-in function to join two 1D arrays into a 2D array?
Consider an example:

```
X=np.array([1,2])
y=np.array([3,4])
result=np.array([[1,3],[2,4]])
```

I can think of 2 simple solutions.
The first one is pretty straightforward.

```
np.transpose([X,y])
```

The other one employs a lambda function.

```
np.array(list(map(lambda i: [a[i],b[i]], range(len(X)))))
```

While the second one looks more complex, it seems to be almost twice as fast as the first one.

**Edit**
A third solution involves the zip() function.

```
np.array(list(zip(X, y)))
```

It's faster than the lambda function but slower than column_stack solution suggested by @Divakar.

```
np.column_stack((X,y))
```

Comment: Use `column_stack` : `np.column_stack((X,y))`.

Comment: This column_stack is quite good, thanks:-).

Comment: @ManishSaraswat it gives a different result!

Comment: The `transpose` operation is effectively `np.array([X,y]).T`.  It has to first make an array, and then apply the transpose method to that.  (I should check the `strides` to verify that)

Comment: The methods that use `transpose` (function or method or property) produce a `F` order array, with strides like (8,16) instead of the usual (16,8).  All the `stack` functions use `np.concatenate`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take into consideration scalability. If we increase the size of the arrays, complete numpy solutions are quite faster than solutions involving python built-in operations:

```
np.random.seed(1234)
X = np.random.rand(10000)
y = np.random.rand(10000)

%timeit np.array(list(map(lambda i: [X[i],y[i]], range(len(X)))))
6.64 ms ± 32.2 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
%timeit np.array(list(zip(X, y)))
4.53 ms ± 33.1 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
%timeit np.column_stack((X,y))
19.2 µs ± 30.5 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
%timeit np.transpose([X,y])
16.2 µs ± 247 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
%timeit np.vstack((X, y)).T
14.2 µs ± 94.5 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
```

Taking into account all proposed solutions, `np.vstack(X,y).T` is the fastest when working with greater array sizes.

Answer (score 3):

This is one way:

```
import numpy as np
X = np.array([1,2])
y = np.array([3,4])
result = np.vstack((X, y)).T
print(result)

# [[1 3]
#  [2 4]]
```

Comment: Looks good but it's slower that the solution with the lambda function.